# How to change background for each page in Wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am redesigning a wordpress blog.There are 5 different pages and i want to use different background images on each of them. Is there any way to do this?

And,i don't want to change the background element. I want to change the background image of the #main element in my css..

I already have a css file so will overwriting the same elements using php affect anything?

Any help will be appreciated...Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Each page or post will have a different class on the body, ie.
page-id-1234
post-id-4567

You can use this to your leverage inside your CSS file:

```
body {
    background: url('home.jpg');
}
body.page-id-1234 {
    background: url('page-1234.jpg');
}
body.post-id-4567 {
    background: url('page-4567.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give each `div#main` (I assume it's a `div`) another class.  So

`<div id="main" class="pageOneBackground">...`

`<div id="main" class="pageTwoBackground">...`

etc...

Then remove the `background-img` from the `div#main` and apply individual `background-img`s to each new class.

This won't affect the php.

Comment: That certainly helped a bit...I will remove the background property from #main and add new classes. But how will i specify the class on the page without changing the wordpress files?

Comment: Use the body tag, which is given a class in wordpress. Its a much cleaner way of doing things.

body.post-id-4567 #main {}

Comment: I don't understand the downvote you're giving, @addedlovely. That's uncalled for.

Comment: @Terry See amustill's answer, adding the class on the body tag lets you target any element on the page, rather than just the one <div>. It's a much cleaner and powerful way to approach things.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background with CSS/URL of image to apply to only the background of the post, only on the background of the home/main page, or both pages. http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-background/screenshots/

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers, to get more understanding how to **not** answer. Namely: "Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question": **barely more than a link to an external site**

Answer (score -1):

If only only need to do it for 5 pages, set the main items of the body in your main CSS, for example:

```
body {
    background-repeat:none;
    background-position: center top;
etc...
```

Then on each page just add:

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-image:url(/images/background1.png);
}
</style>
```

You can also see this on the source of this page.

Comment: Don't do this, keep you CSS in an external file which will make it easier to update. And see my comment above and the answer by @amustill